# mysql REGEXP выборка по слову включая один символ

Tags: mysql, регулярные-выражения

Не могу составить запрос к базе mqsql.
К примеру в базе есть слова:

АБ

АБВ

АБ'В

А'БВ

ВБА

ВБ'А

В'БА

БАВ

Б'АВ

БА'В

Так вот если я задаю поиск найти "АБВ", то мне нужно найти именно "АБВ" и все вариации с символом "`", т.е. должно найтись:
"АБВ", "АБ'В", "А'БВ"

Как такое можно создать регулярным выражением?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Предполагая, что Вам нужен именно апостроф в середине строки, а не *backtick*, и только по одному и только в середине, а не начале или конце: `field REGEXP "^А'?Б'?В$"`. Надеюсь, у Вас достаточно свежий MySQL с полной поддержкой юникода.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Получилось!